# Use of comma in separating ideas in a phrase

Tags: grammar, commas

I ran into an interesting grammatical question while coding yesterday.  We were doing a change to some in-app text, on a page where checks that are no longer valid are registered.

The original text read "Stopped/Voided Checks", because the reason for checks to be stopped is because they have been voided, so the two words are connected in meaning (some checks that are stopped are stopped for different reasons, but they both fall under the same category for our app's purposes)

As part of the change, we also have to include forged checks on this page, so my boss instructed me to change the text to "Stopped/Voided, Forged Checks".

However, I contended that "Stopped/Voided and Forged Checks" seems more gramatically correct.

It also occurs to me that "Stopped/Voided Forged Checks" could be used, or "Stopped/Voided, and Forged Checks".

Which of these instances are most proper?  I'm in favor of "Stopped/Voided and Forged Checks" personally, because it reflects the inclusion of both Stopped/Voided AND Forged checks, but I am not certain that this is correct.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand, but if Stopped and Voided imply the same thing, why not just use one or the other? (i.e. 'Stopped and Forged Checks', or 'Voided and Forged Checks')

Comment: It's for the sake of clarity. Originally it DID just say "Stopped Checks" (Before we also had to include Forged Checks), but there was some confusion over whether Voided Checks should be included, thus the change. Admittedly, we could also change it to "Stopped, Voided and Forged Checks", but at the time I didn't bring it up with my boss.

Comment: If _Stopped/Voided_ is OK because they fall under the same category in your software, what's wrong with _Stopped/Voided/Forged_? Why complicate things when your software doesn't care?

Comment: Because while we don't have to record separate instances of Stopped or Voided checks, we DO have to record instances of Forgeries separate from the other two.  User requirements, sadly, do not always make for good grammar.

Comment: **Stopped (Voided/ Forged/ Other)** if *stopped* is a superset of all other cases. Else **Stopped (Voided/ Other)/ Forged**. One needs to be very careful here: check the set associations.

Comment: meta: Certainly not opinion based because there *will* be a definitive answer, but maybe off-topic because this is basically about set algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't a complete sentence to begin with so I wouldn't worry too much about the rules of grammar and go with clarity.  If stopped and voided checks are largely the same thing, the usage of "stopped/voided" denoting interchangeability in the terms seems appropriate.  As forged checks appear to be a different category, adding in that category with a conjunction, thereby arriving at your suggestion of *Stopped/Voided and Forged Checks*, seems fine.

If stopped and voided checks are even slightly different things, I would suggest *Stopped, Voided, and Forged Checks* would be the way to go.

Comment: "Stopped/Voided" or even "Stopped, Voided"? the two are *not* alternatives. The OP has clarified that well enough.

Comment: @Kris  The OP has definitely not clarified that well enough.

Comment: "... so the two words are connected in meaning (some checks that are stopped are stopped for different reasons, but they both fall under the same category for our app's purposes)" Need more? :)

Comment: @kris-  Some checks that are stopped are voided.  Some that are stopped are stopped for different reasons.  My suggestion was simply that if there is a difference between stopped and voided, as it seems there is, OP should consider treating the categories as a simple comma separated list for the new schema, regardless of how they are treated in the old schema.